# On the definition of differential operator

Tags: macros, math-operators

I've always been using

```
\newcommand*{\dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

to type differential operator. It is sufficient for most cases.

However I just saw a very complicated definition [here](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf#page=8):

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\diff}%
    {\@ifnextchar^{\DIfF}{\DIfF^{}}} 
\def\DIfF^#1{%
    \mathop{\mathrm{\mathstrut d}}% 
        \nolimits^{#1}\gobblespace}
\def\gobblespace{% 
        \futurelet\diffarg\opspace}
\def\opspace{%
        \let\DiffSpace\!%
        \ifx\diffarg(%
            \let\DiffSpace\relax
        \else
            \ifx\diffarg[%
               \let\DiffSpace\relax
            \else
               \ifx\diffarg\{%
                   \let\DiffSpace\relax
               \fi\fi\fi\DiffSpace}
```

I can't understand this code, but it seems that `\diff` creates more whitespace than `\dif`.

Which one is better? Or is there an even better one?

Comment: That code has a history. Claudio Beccari wrote both, the complicated one first, before realizing that the result could be achieved much more simply. And the additional space is due to `^{}` in line 3, which makes TeX add `\scriptspace` that's not actually needed.

Comment: I wrote about it in a [paper on TUGboat](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb41-1/tb127gregorio-math.pdf), pages 47–48.

Comment: I was the one sending the very short version to Claudio. He responded by calling it a Columbus egg. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I use `\mathrm{d}` to conform to the OP's wish, but this doesn't mean I endorse in any way whatsoever the practice, which I consider mathematically wrong.

*Ceterum censeo differentiale signum non esse operatorem.* is my signature on the GuIT forum.

<sup>Cato was known to always end his speeches in the Senate by *Ceterum censeo Carthaginem esse delendam*.</sup>

---

I mentioned the complicated code in a [paper on TUGboat](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb41-1/tb127gregorio-math.pdf). However, I did not really analyze the code and it's a good occasion to.

The surface definition is “check whether a `^` follows and follow the branches”.

If no `^` follows, just `\DIfF^{}` is executed, which is responsible for the small additional space you see, due to TeX adding `\scriptspace` after an atom with a superscript or subscript (even if empty).

Otherwise just `\DIfF` is executed, which *requires* being followed by `^` (after removal of spaces).

It adds `\mathop{\mathrm{\mathstrut d}}\nolimits^{#1}` (the possible superscript to the “d” and then does `\gobblespace`. Why is this needed? Because TeX will add a thin space if an Op atom is followed by an ordinary atom or another Op atom. Hence, without this, we'd get “d<thin space>x” which would be wrong.

The code for `\gobblespace` consists in examining the following nonspace token (spaces are recursively removed): if it is `(` or `[` or `\{`, nothing needs to be done, because TeX won't insert a thin space in those cases. Otherwise (and this is where the code is weak) `\!` is added to compensate for the added thin space.

With `\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}` all this is completely useless: a possible superscript would by to the “d” and not to the Op atom. The thin space between the empty Op atom and the ordinary atom `\mathrm{d}` can be safely removed. TeX will then obey the spacing rules after an ordinary atom.

A visual proof for the problems:

```
\begin{document}

$x\dif x$ $x \dif\langle x\rangle$

$x\diff x$ $x\diff\langle x\rangle$

\scriptspace=0pt

$x\dif x$

$x\diff x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that in the second line there is a small space between “d” and “x” that disappears in the fourth line due to setting `\scriptspace` to zero. In the second line you also see the effect of the forced negative thin space in a situation where it shouldn't be inserted.

Similarly, if you do `\diff\bigl(x+y\bigr)` you'd get a wrong negative space.

Comment: I think I found one instance where `\dif` introduces to much spacing: If we write a differential quotient (inline) as `\dif x / \dif y`, compare to `\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}y`. What would be the best practice for this use case?

Comment: @gerw Inline fractions often need `\!` to fill up holes. The choice is yours: either always adding `\,` in differential forms or always adding `\!` in inline derivatives. Alternatively, define a command for inline derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use `diffcoeff` package to realize a differential operator if you want to define your derivative symbol using upirght `‘d’x` using `\dl` with the spacing fixed of the package. The spaces can be changed.

Here there is a short MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\begin{document}
$\dl.up.x$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]