Spacing around brackets
How can I control the spacing around a bracket? I have the following \newcommands which draw integrals:
\renewcommand{\d}{\,\text{d}#1}
\newcommand{\intT}[1]{\int_0^T#1\d{t}}
\newcommand{\brackets}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\intTb}[1]{\intT{\brackets{#1}}}

So the space between the argument of the integral and the dt should be \,, however in the bracketed version the space between the brackets at the dt is larger - I suspect the brackets are adding some space? The gap before the argument is also slightly larger, though this is harder to see as the gap is already quite large without the brackets - I'm less bothered by this.
MWE
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\d}[1]{\,\text{d}#1}
\newcommand{\intT}[1]{\int_0^T#1\d{t}}
\newcommand{\brackets}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\intTb}[1]{\intT{\brackets{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \intT{t^2}\\
    \intTb{t^2}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    &\intT{t^2}\\
    &\intTb{t^2}
\end{align*}

\end{document}



(1) your use of \text is incorrect (try in an italic context), (2) it is generally a very bad idea to always autoscale using \left...\right, as you see it introduces spacing.

\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d} can be a better definition for \d, but you should not call it \d as it is already defined (it will blow up in your face the day you actually need \d). \dd might be better.

(1) In my context, the command is always going to be inside a math mode, so I think text is fine to get the non-italic d (2) I need to autoscale because the argument of the integral could be anything, fractions, other brackets etc. (3) I'm happy to redefine \d, I don't need to use the underdot

Do you even know what \text does? Try \textit{Test $\text{test}$} not what you want. (you are not the only person to think \text should be used for this.

I see, ok thanks, I didn't understand you were talking about using math mode within an already italic context

You get the same issue if you use the math inside, say, a theorem, which, traditionally, are typeset in italic. Sooo many people see \text as the hammer to solve all their problems.

Are you familiar with the mleftright package? The mleftright package defines the user commands \mleft and \mright, which are generally good for avoiding the problematic horizontal spacing issues caused by \left and \right. However, \mleft and \mright cannot help with delimiters being either too tall (quite frequent) or too little (not as frequent, but it can happen).


You shouldn't redefine \d.

You're explicitly asking for an enlarged space, due to \left and \right.


However, you can mitigate the effect by properly defining the command for the differential.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d} % or \mathrm{d}
\newcommand{\intT}[1]{\int_0^T#1\diff t}
\newcommand{\brackets}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\intTb}[1]{\intT{\brackets{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \intT{t^2}\\
    \intTb{t^2}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    &\intT{t^2}\\
    &\intTb{t^2}
\end{align*}

\end{document}


I'd not use \left and \right, anyway.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\brackets}{\{}{\}}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d} % or \mathrm{d}
\newcommand{\intT}[1]{\int_{0}^{T} #1 \diff t}

\NewDocumentCommand{\intTb}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% * version
    \intT{\brackets*{#3}}%
  }{% normal version
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{% no opt arg
      \intT{\brackets{#3}}%
    }{% opt arg
      \intT{\brackets[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\intT{t^2} \\
&\intTb{t^2} \\
&\intTb[\big]{t^2} \\
&\intTb[\Big]{\frac{t^2}{2}} \\
&\intTb*{\frac{t^2}{2}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}



Thanks. What does \mathop{} do? I know \! is the negative of \,, so instead of increasing the current space by 3mu you've decreased it by 3mu. I don't want to do your NewDocumentCommand method because I have 10 different integral definitions with both a standard and a bracketed version, so I want to keep left and right

@jonnybolton16 You can find the idea behind \diff in the package fixdif, which unfortunately uses \d (and it shouldn't). And no, you don't want to use \left and \right no matter what.

Sorry, I don't understand. How does \mathop{}\! ensure the additional spacing doesn't get added? And I don't understand why I shouldn't want to use left and right

@jonnybolton16 The working of \diff has been explained several times on the site. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581612/4427, for instance. Why avoiding \left and \right as a general rule? Because they tend to use oversized fences.

This doesn't answer my question. \, adds 3mu of space; I can't find anything that explains what \mathop{}\! does but given that I know \! removes 3mu of space and I get the same behaviour from both methods when the brackets aren't there, presumably \mathop{} adds 6mu of space. Why, then, isn't 3mu of space added when \mathop{}\! follows the \right\}? Does this need to be a whole other question?

@jonnybolton16 \mathop{} adds \, on either side (but not under all circumstances) and the possible thin space at the left is what you want for the differential. The thin space on the right is added when an ordinary atom follows: there is indeed one, namely the “d”, and we simply remove it with \!.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
